# Removing string from array using a bi-sectional search

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

I have 2 functions. Function Find goes and does a bi-sectional search meaning it searches the array by sections until it finds the key and returns its location. Function removef or (remove fast) grabs that location and removes it from the string array. I am using a command line interface that asks the user to enter a command and a string (string being removed) so prompting the user for the string is unnecessary.

Here is my Find function

```
int StringList::Find(string key, int start, int end)
{
    int middle = (end + start)/2;
    if (key > str[middle])
    {
        return Find(key,middle,end);
    }
    else if ( key < str[middle])
    {
        return Find(key,start,middle);
    }
    else if (key == str[middle])
    {
        return middle;
    }
}
```

The Find function is supposed to determine whether the key is in the upper section or lower section of the array (above middle or below middle) then keep dividing until it finds the key or string it needs to remove.

Here is removef:

```
void StringList::removef(string s)
{
    int loc = Find(s,0,10000); //ignore these parameters, i know they are wrong they are just an example


        for(int j=loc; j<(numberOfStrings)-1; j++)
        {
            str[j] = str[j+1];
        }
        numberOfStrings--;

}
```

My problem is with my Find function using the bi-sectional search.  Any suggestions on anything I can fix? Im really stuck. Thanks!

Comment: May be a silly question, but is your array sorted? Also, your Find function won't work if the string isn't in the array.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter  Yes it is alphabetically sorted by another function. As for Find not working i will just add an if statement suggesting if its not there to return a -1. if -1 it will print "string not there"

Comment: In that case I would check that it is really sorted at the time the Find function is called. Your code works for me for a sorted array.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter Does not work for me and its sorted. I think my error is in my Find function.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter does it have anything to do with the parameters i am selecting for when i call Find in my removef function?

Comment: What happens if your key actually spans the top half and bottom half of the target array? Or is your key only a single character?

Comment: Well if your array does not actually contain 10,000 strings, yes, those parameters would be a problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one problem I can see is that when the key is greater than the middle element, you are setting the new range to `[midde,end]`, but it should be `[middle+1,end]` - there's no point in considering the middle element again, because you already know it's not a match.

So that first condition should look like this:

```
if (key > str[middle])
{
    return Find(key,middle+1,end);
}
```

Also, as others have mentioned, you'll need a check to see if the string isn't in the array. I'd suggest adding something like this at the start of your `Find` method.

```
if (start == end) return -1;
```

Once you've subdivided the array down to the point that the start equals the end, there's no more space to search and your string wron't be found.

Other than that, the only thing I can think might be wrong is that you're calling the `Find` method with the wrong range. It should be called like this:

```
int loc = Find(s,0,numberOfStrings);
```

Comment: You sir saved my life! The error was the call to Find in my remove function

Answer (score 1):

To begin, I am assuming that you have already sorted the string 'str' array...otherwise a binary search won't work.

In your 'Find' function you access the 'str' array which I am assuming is your string array, however you do not pass this array as a parameter.  So, unless it is a global array attempting to access it will not work.

Finally, since you are calling this function recursively, you need to have a case that handles the string not being contained in the array at all.

Comment: I have a class called StringList as written above that has that str[] array in it. My sequential search works. My bisectional search does not. I can simply write an if statement to fix the string not being there

Comment: No it does not @Greysquall